# Javascript axios post after a while loop async / promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await, axios

I'm new with async/await and I need a litle help. 
What I would like to achive is to send and axios post request after a while loop finished.

How can I put the while loop in an async function and await for it?

This is the current code:

```
showResults: function () {
            let vm = this;


            let apiUrl = '/api/test';
            let randomCallCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (80 - 50 + 1) + 50);
            let start = 1;

            while (start <= randomCallCount) {
                let randomChars = [...Array(40)].map(i => (~~(Math.random() * 36)).toString(36)).join('');
                fetch('https://' + randomChars + '.ipleak.net/json/?query_type=mydns')
                        .then((resp) => resp.json())
                        .then(function (data) {
                            vm.dnsResult.push(data);
                        });

                start++;
            }

            axios.post(apiUrl, {lat: vm.geoLat, lon: vm.geoLon, dns: vm.dnsResult})...
```

I thought maybe something like this, but this one is not working:

```
            fetchDNSData: async function () {
            let vm = this;
            let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let randomCallCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (80 - 50 + 1) + 50);
                let start = 1;

                while (start <= randomCallCount) {
                    let randomChars = [...Array(40)].map(i => (~~(Math.random() * 36)).toString(36)).join('');
                    fetch('https://' + randomChars + '.ipleak.net/json/?query_type=mydns')
                            .then((resp) => resp.json())
                            .then(function (data) {
                                vm.dnsResult.push(data);
                            });

                    start++;
                }
            });

            let result = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves (*)

            return result;
        },

        showResults: function () {
            let vm = this;


            let apiUrl = '/api/test';

            vm.fetchDNSData().then(
                    response => {
                        axios.post(apiUrl, {lat: vm.geoLat, lon: vm.geoLon, dns: vm.dnsResult})...
```

Any suggestion what can show me the right direction? :) Thanks a lot

Comment: You have not resolved promise anywhere. Also, you can directly add `await` to `fetch` and `res.json()`

Comment: In the first snippet all `fetch` calls and `axios.post` will be run "in parallel", because all of them are asynchronous. In synchronous code the line below is always executed after the line above was completed, but in asynchronous code these relations should be established explicitly. `await` is one of ways to do it. If you just want all requests to execute sequentially, it would be enough to insert `await` before `fetch` and before `axios.post`, but mixing `await` and `then` complicates understanding, so you can follow the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58931813/1531945)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use async/await, you should not use `then`. Use `await` instead of `then`.
The below example should be what you need.

```
showResults: async function () {
            let vm = this;


            let apiUrl = '/api/test';
            let randomCallCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (80 - 50 + 1) + 50);
            let start = 1;

            while (start <= randomCallCount) {
                let randomChars = [...Array(40)].map(i => (~~(Math.random() * 36)).toString(36)).join('');
                const response = await fetch('https://' + randomChars + '.ipleak.net/json/?query_type=mydns');
                const data = await response.json();
                vm.dnsResult.push(data);

                start++;
            }

            axios.post(apiUrl, {lat: vm.geoLat, lon: vm.geoLon, dns: vm.dnsResult})...
```

Comment: You omitted `then` but didn't provide `await`. `response.json()` is a promise.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes, I had written mistakenly wrong. I have fixed the issue. Thanks